# Prevent GridView from going under the toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I've got a GridView filled with an adapter. The display is working for every item in my gridView. But I have a problem my gridView is going under the toolbar when the main activity is displayed. Here is my code : 

actyvity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.mtoy.laboiteasqueezie.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.mtoy.android.recyclerview.MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#d6d6d6">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:columnWidth="150dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

items in my GridView :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:minHeight="150dp"
    android:paddingBottom="6dp"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:paddingRight="6dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#898A8A"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm sure the solution must be simple but I can't figure out what it is. Can you help me with that please ?

Comment: What do you mean "going under the toolbar"? Post a screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line to your Relative Layout

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```